# download button in shinyR getting a download.html if I don't wait enough time

Tags: r, shiny, download, officer

I have a download button that creates a word document using images downloaded from AWS. Libraries officer and S3, mainly. this word document loads information when the file is selected.

If my user doesn't waits enough time to load the whole information, specially if there are many images, we get a download.html, but some seconds later trying again we get the word document as expected.

Is there a way to know if the whole information is fully loaded or the word document is really ready to download?

If any has some tips after experiencing something similar, I would appreciate it.
It's really complex to create a "reproducible example", so I'll go for a conceptual solution.

Thank you